# If $X$ is gamma distributed, find the distribution of $Y=1/X$

Tags: probability, statistics

Some help with this would be much appreciated,

Given that $X$ has a gamma distribution, find the probability density function of $Y = 1/X$.

I can get that $P(Y < x) = P(X > 1/x)$ but not really sure where to go from here,

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean to find the probability density function? Probability mass functions are something that discrete variables have.

Comment: Yes I suppose I do! thanks

Comment: Try to use the [change of variables formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function#Dependent_variables_and_change_of_variables).

Comment: So in this case it has the same distribution then as 1/x is self-inverse? EDIT: Nope, i need to multiply by x^-2 on the outside.

Comment: If $X$ ~ Gamma(a,b), then 1/X ~ InverseGamma(a,b). Google may be your friend ... though take care as multiple 'definitions' / paramaterisations exist.

Answer (score 3):

Following @StefanHansen's comment, note that
$$P(Y\lt y)=P(X\gt1/y)=\int_{1/y}^{+\infty}f_X(x)\mathrm dx\stackrel{(x=1/t)}{=}\int_0^yf_X\left(\frac1t\right)\frac{\mathrm dt}{t^2},
$$
hence
$$
f_Y(y)=\frac1{y^2}f_X\left(\frac1y\right).
$$

Answer (score 1):

The pdf of a gamma distributed variable is

$f_{X}(x) = \frac{1}{\Gamma(a) b^a} x^{a-1} e^{-x/b}$.

Using the transformation $Y = 1/X$ we have $X = 1/Y$ and $\frac{d}{dy} = -\frac{1}{y^2}$.

Using the following structure
$f_{Y}(y) = f_{X}\bigg( \frac{1}{y} \bigg) \bigg| - \frac{1}{y^2} \bigg|$,
we can obtain the following:

$f_{Y}(y) = \frac{1}{\Gamma(a) b^a} x^{a-1} e^{-1/yb} * \frac{1}{y^2} = \frac{1}{\Gamma(a) b^a} \bigg( \frac{1}{y}\bigg)^{a + 1} e^{-1/yb},$
where $0 \le y < \infty$.

Hope this helps and good luck!!!